# Ninja Form on WordPress get post_id value on my_ninja_forms_after_submission

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I created a form that create a specific post type and everything is working well but, based on this form, I want to set up some tags I use for filters. The creation part works well but the 'wp_set_object_terms' is not working as, has I call 'my_ninja_forms_after_submission' and set up my method, the only post_id I got from $form_data is not the right one. Checking my 'posts' table in the db I discovered that, on submit, I got 4 different row created, probably for the form structure and content but calling `$post_id = $form_data['actions']['save']['sub_id']` on 'my_ninja_forms_after_submission' I got only the last ID of the 4 row. Has you can see in the screen I took, I got the id pointed with the red harrow instead of the blue one.

[image]

Anyone has experience about that and know I can get the right post_id value?

Many thanks

Comment: just to understad, I see those rows are about different post statuses, do you need to get the ID of the post with `post_status = publish`?

Comment: Hi @GrafiCode, thanks for your question and time. No, I get the first value you see (in this specific case '10665') but I need to get the last one (in this screen case '10662') that is my post_id. The status is 'draft' has I set this way to let admin check it before publish it.

Comment: looking at the modify date of both rows, it looks like it is the same post... Is it possible that your WP installation is using an auto-drafting plugin which creates revisions upon saving?

Comment: Uhm no, seems not. Even tried to add to my config-php this: `define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);

define('AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL', 9999 );` but still generate 4 db rows for the same post submit. I'm starting thinking that is something related to ninja form directly but I think is really curious that I can't access to my post_id after itself creation.